# Problem with the usage of std::transform in C++

Tags: c++, transform

While solving a question related to Operator Overloading, I ran into a problem. I will now describe the specifics of the problem.

The code contains a class named `Matrix` and is defined as follow:

```
class Matrix {
   public:
    std::vector<std::vector<int>> a;
    friend Matrix operator+(const Matrix& x, const Matrix& b);
};
```

I am supposed to find the addition of two matrices by overloading the `+` operator.

Initially, I decided to use the `transform` function to perform the addition of two matrices and came up with the following code which ***does not yield*** the correct answer for all the test cases,

```
Matrix operator+(const Matrix& x, const Matrix& y) {
    Matrix result;
    result.a.reserve(x.a.size());
    for (size_t i = 0; i < x.a.size(); i++) {
        std::transform(x.a.at(i).begin(), x.a.at(i).end(), y.a.at(i).begin(),
                       std::back_inserter(result.a[i]), std::plus<int>());
    }
    return result;
}
```

So, I am forced to the same task with a nested for loop, which ***yields*** the correct answer for all the test cases, as follows:

```
Matrix operator+(const Matrix& x, const Matrix& y) {
    Matrix result;
    std::vector<int> vec;
    result.a.reserve(x.a.size());
    for (size_t i = 0; i < x.a.size(); i++) {
        vec.reserve(x.a.at(i).size());
        for (size_t j = 0; j < x.a.at(i).size(); j++) {
            vec.push_back(x.a.at(i).at(j) + y.a.at(i).at(j));
        }
        result.a.push_back(vec);
        vec.clear();
    }
    return result;
}
```

I am failing to see what is wrong with the `transform` version. Can anybody point out the error in the code? Any help is appreciated. Thanks.

Comment: Can you provide a [mcve] including the data that gives an incorrect result?

Comment: This is a question from Hackerrank, which gives me correct answers for all base cases but the wrong answer for every hidden case. Also, the test cases are way too large for me to copy and paste here.

Comment: Without any information on the type of test case this code might encounter, and no actual data to show it isn't working I'm afraid you'll have an uphill battle here. Perhaps be satisfied with the version that does work, or get busy with a debugger to figure out where the algorithms differ. Good luck!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Undefined behavior. Elements are reserved but not added to the vector:

```
result.a.reserve(x.a.size()); // result.a is still empty
for (size_t i = 0; i < x.a.size(); i++) {
    std::transform(x.a.at(i).begin(), x.a.at(i).end(), y.a.at(i).begin(),
                   std::back_inserter(result.a[i] /* UB */ ), std::plus<int>());
}
```

Call `result.a.resize()` instead.